# DateTime Won't Load Properly Unless a Module Using Moo Launches First

Tags: perl, datetime, moo

I'm cleaning up code and removed the now deprecated `Forecast::IO` module from my Perl script. When I did, I started getting this error:

```
[root@server cgi-bin]# perl Weather.pm
Undefined subroutine &B::perlstring called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Params/ValidationCompiler/Compiler.pm line 248.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/DateTime.pm line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/DateTime.pm line 13.
Compilation failed in require at Weather.pm line 1340.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Weather.pm line 1340.
```

Line 1340 where the error occurs is innocuously enough, `use DateTime;`.

I wasn't sure what `DateTime` could be up to that would cause it to be upset I wasn't using the unrelated `Forecast::IO` module any longer, so I started taking apart the latter module to figure out what code was preventing the error. The essential part seems to be that `Moo` is included in `Forecast::IO` and it has at least one Moo `has` declaration:

```
package Forecast::IO;
use Moo;
has testkey => ( is => 'ro' ); 
1;
```

For some reason, if that module with at least those lines exists, DateTime loads fine. Otherwise, the error I mentioned above occurs, choking on DateTime's line 13, `use Carp;`. Even if I put `use Moo; has testkey => ( is => 'ro' );` into my own module, it fails upon `use DateTime`.

Even though I've used `grep -r Forecast::IO` to traverse the codebase to look for some errant reference and come up empty. So, I decided to try to *just* load the DateTime module: `perl -MDateTime`. That too produces the error:

```
[root@server cgi-bin]# perl -MDateTime
Undefined subroutine &B::perlstring called at     /usr/local/share/perl5/Params/ValidationCompiler/Compiler.pm line 248.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/DateTime.pm line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/DateTime.pm line 13.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

Comment: The error is about `B::perstring` missing, first called at line 340 (nearest to 248 the error reports) in `Params::ValidationCompiler::Compiler`. What version of these modules do you have?

Comment: I have `B::C` 1.57 and `Params::ValidationCompiler` 0.30. Interestingly, I just upgraded `DateTime` from CPAN and that seems to have fixed the error. I'm curious why `DateTime` broke and why having that `Moo` based module somehow "fixed" it, but with the current release of DateTime, the error goes away without having to require `Forecast::IO`.

Comment: Ah, that may explain it.  The weird thing is that it doesn't complain about `use B qw(perlstring);`  -- but it does about using it later.  So I guess things may have been different (broken?) in earlier versions.  But so all is well for you now? :)

Comment: @zdim Yes, thankfully! Thank you for the help. I'm curious what was going on, but at least it is working now!

Comment: Alright :),  This definitely triggers my curiosity as well ... It is a great summary of reasons why I am restrained with using the full power of CPAN: often all kinds of code gets involved, so much so that I have no way to check what some of not-so-well-tested code is doing.  (But then of course there are all the good reasons for using it fully...)

Comment: @zdim Good point! I'm really surprised I haven't noticed more such issues in the past. Thanks again! :-)